# Can a space be both an $n$- and $m$-manifold, where $m \neq n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I've yet to formally learn about manifolds, but we've briefly mentioned them in topology (we're talking about surfaces, which are 2-manifolds). And, from what I know, a topological space is an $n$-manifold if every point $p\in X$ is contained in some open neighborhood $U$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, let's consider the $2$-sphere with the discrete topology. Since the discrete topology is finer than the standard topology, and the $2$-sphere with the standard topology is a $2$-manifold, then clearly every point on the $2$-sphere with the discrete topology is also contained in some open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, the $2$-sphere with the standard topology is a $2$-manifold.

Now, since we're in the discrete topology, for every $p\in S^2$, the set $\{p\}$ is an open neighborhood of $p$. Let $\mathbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$. Thus, the topology on $\mathbb{R}^0$ must be $\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$, and therefore is the discrete topology. Thus, $\{p\}$ and  $\{0\}$ are necessarily homeomorphic. Hence, the $2$-sphere is a $0$-manifold.

Also, another question, if this is true, does that mean an $n$-dimensional object could be an $m$-manifold where $m\neq n$, because the $2$-sphere is a $2$-dimensional object but I tried to show it's a $0$-manifold.

I know that I must be wrong, so if anybody could point out where I messed up, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "Since the discrete topology is finer than the standard topology, and the $2$-sphere with the standard topology is a $2$-manifold, then clearly every point on the $2$-sphere with the discrete topology is also contained in some open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$." That is false. The neighbourhood which used to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard topology is no longer homeomorphic to it with the discrete topology.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz OHH I see I see, because the condition that the bijection and its inverse must both be continuous this fails.

Comment: exactly. I realise I actually answered in the comments. Do you want me to type it up in the comments or do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: There is precisely one such space, the empty set.